# On TextView.setText(string) null pointer exception occurs

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to update some `TextViews`. I have 3 Layout `Main_Activity.XML` For default `Portrait` and `Landscape`. The `TextView` in those layouts all have the same `andoid:id`

I have read everything I can on updating the `TextView` and have no idea why this is crashing the whole app.

I think maybe `TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewActiveTimeProp1)` is returning a null and then when I try to `setText` I get a null pointer exception. Any thoughts? I have put the

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewActiveTimeProp1);
String strPref = retrievePrefs("pref_active_times_prop1");
txt.setText(strPref);
```

In a `Button` `onclick` event that occurs long after the `setContentView` has completed with the same results above. Verified that the id's I am using to reference the `TextView` exit in all 3 of my layouts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewActiveTimeProp1);
String strPref = retrievePrefs("pref_active_times_prop1");
txt.setText(strPref);
}
```

Comment: why not just use `""` instead of `null`?

Comment: You are talking about three layouts. The rule is, you can get access to a resource like textview or imageview for the layout that you are setting in the setContentView(). If you set a layout 1 in the setContentView() and try access a resource from another layout, you will get null.

Comment: Just check txt (your TextView) on null like :
Log.d(TAG, "TextView is null : "+String.valueOf(findViewById(R.id.txtViewActiveTimeProp1)==null));

Answer (score 1):

Hi You have to do findViewById inside onCreate method.
since you are doing findViewById inside event listener it is returning null.

Do the below mentioned changes in your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewActiveTimeProp1);
String strPref = retrievePrefs("pref_active_times_prop1");
txt.setText(strPref);
}
```

and inside your click listener

```
String strPref = retrievePrefs("pref_active_times_prop1");
txt.setText(strPref);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the value String strPref = retrievePrefs("pref_active_times_prop1");
 is coming null , print that strPref value and check

Comment: the strPref Value is returned it is currently set to 1000 and if i make a preference change that is reflected.